# Expected value of $R^2$ for linear regression of two normal vectors

Tags: regression, probability

How can we calculate the expected R-squared for a linear regression model without intercept where the predictor variable x and the response variable y are both 100-dimensional standard normal vectors?

I tried the following R code and got the output. It looks complicated to compute the expectation of $$1-R^2 = SS_{\mathrm{res}}/SS_{\mathrm{tot}} = \mathbb{E}\left[\frac{\left\|\left(\frac{xx^\top}{\|x\|^2 } - I\right)y\right\|^2}{\|y-11^\top y\|^2}\right]$$.

---

Edit Feb 27, 2023:

I just realized that it appears that $SS_{\mathrm{tot}}$ (in the without-intercept case) should not be $\|y-11^\top y\|_2^2$, but rather $\|y\|^2$. Am I correct? Also, as a follow-up question, what is the distribution of $R^2$? I suppose it could be a Beta distribution.

```
> set.seed(123)
> 
> # Define number of iterations
> n_iter <- 10000
> 
> # Create a vector to store R-squared values
> rsq_values <- numeric(n_iter)
> 
> # Loop through iterations
> for (i in 1:n_iter) {
+     # Generate x and y as 100-dimensional standard normal vectors
+     x <- rnorm(100, mean = 0, sd = 1)
+     y <- rnorm(100, mean = 0, sd = 1)
+     
+     # Perform linear regression of y on x without intercept
+     model <- lm(y ~ x - 1)
+     
+     # Store R-squared value
+     rsq_values[i] <- summary(model)$r.squared
+ }
> 
> # Calculate average R-squared
> mean_rsq <- mean(rsq_values)
> mean_rsq
[1] 0.01005497
```

Comment: Your simulation suggests a little bit more than $\frac1{100}$.  That seems plausible - my simulations suggest  $E[r^2]=\frac1{n-1}$ if the two variables are in fact independent

Comment: A symmetry argument implies that the expected value is $\rho^2 + (1-\rho^2)/n$ where $n=100$ and $\rho$ is the correlation between $x$ and $y$. If $x$ and $y$ are independent, then the expectation is just $1/n$.

Comment: Thanks @GordonSmyth ! Would you mind explaining a little bit more on the symmetry argument?

Comment: I am wondering why you are particularly interested in the case "without intercept". Isn't the case "with intercept" more frequently encountered? In addition, what you listed is not $R^2$ but $1−R^2$ in the with intercept case.

Comment: Thanks @Zhanxiong This is not a problem that arises from practice, but rather a question that I was asked :)

Comment: @Alex At least you can correct the terminology? Again,  $SSE/SST$ is not the commonly known $R^2$.

Comment: Thanks @Zhanxiong I understand that $SSE/SST = 1-R^2$. I tried to find the expected value of $R^2$ through the expected value of $SSE/SST$. Sorry for the confusion and I made the edit.